# Microsoft.Data.SqlClient support with Full .NET Framework Entity Framework 6 or later version?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

My application runs on .NET framework 4.8 and I'm using Entity Framework 6.0. Currently, my code uses some classes from the namespace System.Data.SqlClient such as SqlParameter, SQLCommand. I want to switch to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.

However, It looks like EF6 is not compatible with Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.

I can't upgrade my application to any EFCore version (This is huge effort).

Can someone please guide me how to switch to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient with EF6?

Does anyone know that is Microsoft planning to add support for Microsoft.Data.SqlClient in future version of EF7/EF8 (Full .net framework only)?

Thanks

I searched on Internet but couldn't find any correct answer.

Comment: `Entity Framework 6.0` is the legacy version .NET Framework version that uses `System.Data.SqlClient` only. The product is in maintenance mode. There's no EF 7/8 nor will there ever be. All new development goes into Entity Framework Core

Comment: .NET Framework isn't "full" either, it's legacy, also in maintenance mode. All new development, all features, including for WPF, Windows Forms, goes into .NET Core. .NET 5,6,7,8 are actually .NET *Core 5-8. There won't be a .NET Framework 5

Comment: Thanks but MS says in below link that they plan to add support for using EF6 with Microsoft.Data.SqlClient   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/plan#theme-clear-path-forward-from-ef6

Comment: That's an aspirational single line in a different product's doc page. If you search EF6 Legacy's Github repo you'll see that [this isn't ready yet](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/issues/823) and the actual solution is to copy ErikEJ's implementation - actually, the pull request came from ErikEJ himself. As he says, if you want a solution today, you'll have to [use his provider](https://github.com/ErikEJ/EntityFramework6PowerTools/blob/community/src/ErikEJ.EntityFramework.SqlServer/readme.md)

Comment: One can only guess that since the GH issue was closed as fixed by ErikEJ's fix 3 months ago it will be included in 6.4.5 whenever that's released. Given that 6.4.4 was released in May 2020, one could bet they'll release it during MS Build. Or not. Even then it will be behind ErikEJ's later versions

Comment: I agree with you Panagiotis. Thanks for this update.

Answer (score 4):

The current plan is to release an official new provider for EntityFramework 6.5 later this year - Microsoft.EntityFramwork.SqlServer, and hopefully preview it earlier.

This provider will use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient

In the meantime you can use [my provider](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ErikEJ.EntityFramework.SqlServer), which is already widely used (more than 500.000 Nuget downloads)

Comment: Is the release date Build-related?

Comment: No, later in the year

Comment: Thanks, @ErikEJ. This bit us hard. After switching to the MDS driver, we'd get this error when trying to call a stored procedure with parameters: `The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not SqlParameter objects.` Your library saved us! Thank you!